# xcode storyboard mirroring effect

Tags: xcode, storyboard

Am using Xcode 9.1 and [my Xcode error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RG6G4.png) while dragging objects from object panel in storyboard its mirroring automatically as shown in picture .need help in solving this !

Answer (score 0):

Very odd. At first I thought it was simply rendering for a RtL locale but I don't imagine the chrome around the rendered view should be mirrored as well. Out of curiosity are you testing a Right-to-Left locale? If so, does this persist when that preference is disabled?

Otherwise I'd try cleaning the project, restarting Xcode, and removing your `.xcuserdatad` file, in that order.